# Replicating a table

Tags: html-table

I'm having trouble replicating this table. I'm confused with the `rowspan` and `colspan`. I would really appreciate it if someone helps.

[Click here to view image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4cZg.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is not a code writing service. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">The Error Rate on Different Forms</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Form name</td>
        <td rowspan="2">A</td>
        <td rowspan="2">B</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Total Fields (X = A x B)</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Fields with errors (Y)</td>
        <td colspan="2">Error rate* (Y/X) x 100 (%)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>X/Y</td>
        <td>%age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">High Risk Errors</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- normal tr td -->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">Low Risk Error</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- normal tr td -->
</table>
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]